# Simple programmable text editor with multiple terminals (linux)

Tags: linux, text-editor

I'm searching for a linux gui text editor with the possibility to have multiple terminal sessions inside of the text editor. Copy paste should be possible with Ctrl c Ctrl v both in the files and in the terminal. It should include some "jump to definition" (not necessarily out-of-the-box).

Emacs with multi-term is nearly perfect, but it is a nightmare to get copy paste with Ctrl c Ctrl v working in multi-term.

I'm looking for something like emacs but with easier configuration and scripting.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I misunderstood your question, but I was able to force this binding by reading the comments on the [wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MultiTerm).

Editing the multi-term.el file (if installed via M-x package-install) (located ~/emacs.d/elpa/multi-term-1.2/multi-term.el

Remove "C-c" from the term-unbind-key-list:

```
(defcustom term-unbind-key-list
  '("C-z" "C-x" "C-h" "C-y" "<ESC>")
  "The key list that will need to be unbind."
  :type 'list
  :group 'multi-term)
```

Change the term-bind-key-alist defaults, here I'm using C-c maybe you want C-c-c:

```
> (defcustom term-bind-key-alist  
>    '(
>     ("C-c" . kill-ring-save)
>     ("C-p" . previous-line)
>     ("C-v" . term-paste)
>       .....
```

[Recompile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1217249/8120802): `M-x byte-recompile-directory`

Restart emacs and `Ctrl-V` and `Ctrl-C` work as you want them to while in multi-term.

Comment: I'm well aware of the existance of the Cua-Mode. But unfortunately Cua-Mode does not work with multi-term. (see https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/50920/ctrl-c-ctrl-v-copy-paste-in-multi-term)

Comment: Fixed my answer, these bindings work on my local machine.

Comment: This works for multi-term, but I want to use C-c and C-v both in multi-term and when editing a file. Once I put a (cua-mode t) in my init.el I can't copy paste in multi-term.

Answer (score 0):

[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) can do that.

To open a new terminal, type `Alt-T, N`. To split current terminal type `ctrl-shift-s`.

I've assigned my own keystrokes to switch from terminal-window 1 to main editor window as `ctrl-1`, and from main editor window to terminal1 as `ctrl-2`.

To switch from terminal-window 1 to 2, use `arrow-right`, to switch back use  `arrow-left`.

You can also select text inside the terminal window, but I use the mouse to do that. once text is selected, `ctrl-c`, `ctrl-v` works too.

There are also Keymaps available as Extensions for VSCode, enabling you to import settings from other common editors).

Comment: VSCode is not bad, but I prefer to have a tabbed view of terminals so that the current terminal or the current file takes up most of the screen. (like in emacs multi-tab)